# Loading Json Array File in Hive

Tags: json, hive

I have a file which contains the data as follows

```
[{"col1":"col1","col2":1}
,{"col1":"col11","col2":11}
,{"col1":"col111","col2":2}
]
```

I am trying to load the table in Hive.

I am using following Hive serde

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table (
      my_array ARRAY<struct<col1:string,col2:int>>
)ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "ignore.malformed.json" = "true")
LOCATION "MY_LOCATION";
```

I am getting error when I try to run select * after running the create command -

```
['*org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException:java.io.IOException: org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected:25:24', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:499', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.OperationManager:getOperationNextRowSet:OperationManager.java:307', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionImpl:fetchResults:HiveSessionImpl.java:878', 'sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor29:invoke::-1', 'sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl:invoke:DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43', 'java.lang.reflect.Method:invoke:Method.java:498', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:78', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:access$000:HiveSessionProxy.java:36', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy$1:run:HiveSessionProxy.java:63', 'java.security.AccessController:doPrivileged:AccessController.java:-2', 'javax.security.auth.Subject:doAs:Subject.java:422', 'org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation:doAs:UserGroupInformation.java:1698', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.session.HiveSessionProxy:invoke:HiveSessionProxy.java:59', 'com.sun.proxy.$Proxy35:fetchResults::-1', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.CLIService:fetchResults:CLIService.java:559', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.thrift.ThriftCLIService:FetchResults:ThriftCLIService.java:751', 'org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1717', 'org.apache.hive.service.rpc.thrift.TCLIService$Processor$FetchResults:getResult:TCLIService.java:1702', 'org.apache.thrift.ProcessFunction:process:ProcessFunction.java:39', 'org.apache.thrift.TBaseProcessor:process:TBaseProcessor.java:39', 'org.apache.hive.service.auth.TSetIpAddressProcessor:process:TSetIpAddressProcessor.java:56', 'org.apache.thrift.server.TThreadPoolServer$WorkerProcess:run:TThreadPoolServer.java:286', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor:runWorker:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149', 'java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker:run:ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624', 'java.lang.Thread:run:Thread.java:748', '*java.io.IOException:org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException: java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected:29:4', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getNextRow:FetchOperator.java:521', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:pushRow:FetchOperator.java:428', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchTask:fetch:FetchTask.java:147', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver:getResults:Driver.java:2207', 'org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation:getNextRowSet:SQLOperation.java:494', '*org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.SerDeException:java.io.IOException: Start token not found where expected:30:1', 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe:deserialize:JsonSerDe.java:184', 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.FetchOperator:getNextRow:FetchOperator.java:502', '*java.io.IOException:Start token not found where expected:30:0', 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe:deserialize:JsonSerDe.java:170'], statusCode=3), results=None, hasMoreRows=None)
```

I tried several things, none of which worked as expected. I can't change the input data format as it is someone else who is providing the data.

Answer (score 1):

This is a malformed JSON issue. A JSON file will always have "curly braces" at the beginning and the end. So change your JSON file to look something like below.

```
{"my_array":[{"col1":"col1","col2":1},{"col1":"col11","col2":11},{"col1":"col111","col2":2}]}
```

Create your table in the exact same way as you are doing it already.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE my_table 
(
      my_array ARRAY<struct<col1:string,col2:int>>
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( "ignore.malformed.json" = "true")
LOCATION "MY_LOCATION";
```

Now fire a `select *` on your newly created table to see following results.

> [{"col1":"col1","col2":1},{"col1":"col11","col2":11},{"col1":"col111","col2":2}]

Use `select my_array.col1 from my_table;` to see the values for col1 from your array.

> ["col1","col11","col111"]

---

***PS - Not the most efficient way to store the data. Consider    transforming the data and storing it as ORC/Parquet.***

---

Hope that helps!

Comment: The last query should be `select my_array.col1 from my_table;`

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, Manoj. I have updated the answer to include the array column name.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue is with your json data. Can you try with below example?

Create employee json with below content and place it in hdfs.

```
[root@quickstart spark]# hadoop fs -cat /user/cloudera/spark/employeejson/*
{"Name":"Vinayak","age":35}
{"Name":"Nilesh","age":37}
{"Name":"Raju","age":30}
{"Name":"Karthik","age":28}
{"Name":"Shreshta","age":1}
{"Name":"Siddhish","age":2}
```

Add below jar(execute only if you get any error. )

```
hive> ADD JAR /usr/lib/hive-hcatalog/lib/hive-hcatalog-core.jar;

hive> 
CREATE TABLE employeefromjson(name string, age int)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hive.hcatalog.data.JsonSerDe'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/user/cloudera/hive/employeefromjson'
;

hive> LOAD DATA INPATH '/user/cloudera/spark/employeejson' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE employeefromjson;

hive> select * from employeefromjson;
OK
Vinayak 35
Nilesh  37
Raju    30
Karthik 28
Shreshta    1
Siddhish    2
Time taken: 0.174 seconds, Fetched: 6 row(s)
```

Comment: The example you are referring to is json row one per line. The data I have shared is a json array. Both the datasets look correct to me.

I am able to read json like yours, but failing in reading json array structure like I posted.

Answer (score 0):

A JSON should always start with `'{'` and not with `'['`. That is the problem. As you know, JSON has a structure of `{'key':'value'}`. What you have given in your file is a value which does not have any key. So, change your JSON to the below formmat

```
{"my_array":[{"col1":"col1","col2":1},{"col1":"col11","col2":11},{"col1":"col111","col2":2}]}
```

Your `Create table` statement should work fine.

If you want to get the data for each column for all the rows, use the below query.

```
select my_array.col1, my_array.col2 from my_table;
```

The above command will give you the below result.

```
 OK
["col1","col11","col111"]       [1,11,2]
```

If you want to get the result column wise for each row seperately, use the below query.

```
select a.* from my_table m lateral view outer inline (m.my_array) a;
```

The above command will give you the below result.

```
OK
col1    1
col11   11
col111  2
```

Hope you this helps!